# Prevent need to press Command+D after multiline input in Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python program uses `keyphrase = sys.stdin.readlines()` to take user input. Once complete the user must press `Command+D` to continue with program execution. The particular text that the user will be inputting will be pasted into the terminal. Is it possible to change from `Command+D` to `Enter`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) might be the right choice here.

It's a little hacky, but `fileinput.input()` without any arguments calls `sys.stdin.readlines()` and gives us a context-manager which we can use to parse the inputs separately.

```
import fileinput
var = ""
with fileinput.input() as F:
    for line in F:
        if line == "\n":
            F.close()
        else:
            var += line

print(var)
```

Inside of the `for-loop` we are reading the latest input-value, which means that we can parse the given input, and then make a decision for how to proceed.

`sys.stdin.readlines()` standardizes the newlines that it is given, which means that we can expect that an empty line (enter press) will return `'\n'`. If that is true, then we close the stream.